# MSYS: Error c compiler cannot create executables

Tags: c, mingw, libxml2

I'm trying build libxml2 on MinGW following [this](http://www.pokorra.de/coding/compile_libxml_mingw.html) tutorial. But when I run `/.configure` on MSYS terminal I get:

```
 ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/c/Users/name/Documents/libxml2-2.4.25-special/missing: Unknown `--run' option
Try `/c/Users/name/Documents/libxml2-2.4.25-special/missing --help' for more i                                             nformation
configure: WARNING: `missing' script is too old or missing
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables                                             eate executables
check `config.log' for details.
```

I'd tried by setting 755 on libxml2 directory, but nothing changed.

How to fix this?

**EDIT** the `config.log` file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.54.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = username-PC
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.0.9(0.46/3/2)
uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.1
uname -v = 2003-07-03 07:26

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
hostinfo               = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: .
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /mingw/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live
PATH: /c/Windows/system32
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1491: checking build system type
configure:1509: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:1517: checking host system type
configure:1531: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:1570: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:1624: result: /bin/install -c
configure:1635: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:1678: result: yes
configure:1703: WARNING: `missing' script is too old or missing
configure:1711: checking for gawk
configure:1727: found /bin/gawk
configure:1737: result: gawk
configure:1747: checking whether make sets ${MAKE}
configure:1767: result: yes
configure:1966: checking for gcc
configure:1982: found /mingw/bin/gcc
configure:1992: result: gcc
configure:2234: checking for C compiler version
configure:2237: gcc --version </dev/null >&5
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.7.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2240: $? = 0
configure:2242: gcc -v </dev/null >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.0/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.0 (GCC) 
configure:2245: $? = 0
configure:2247: gcc -V </dev/null >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2250: $? = 1
configure:2270: checking for C compiler default output
configure:2273: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
configure:2276: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
#line 2253 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int
main ()
{

  ;
  return 0;
}
configure:2303: error: C compiler cannot create executables
check `config.log' for details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_build_alias=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_F77_set=
ac_cv_env_F77_value=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_host_alias=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_path_install='/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='aclocal-1.6'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='tar'
ANSI2KNR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF='autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='automake-1.6'
AWK='gawk'
C14N_OBJ=''
CATALOG_OBJ=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEBUG_OBJ=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DOCB_OBJ=''
ECHO='echo'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F77=''
FFLAGS=''
FTP_OBJ=''
HAVE_ISINF=''
HAVE_ISNAN=''
HTML_DIR=''
HTML_OBJ=''
HTTP_OBJ=''
ICONV_LIBS=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='${SHELL} $(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBXML_MAJOR_VERSION='2'
LIBXML_MICRO_VERSION='25'
LIBXML_MINOR_VERSION='4'
LIBXML_VERSION='2.4.25'
LIBXML_VERSION_INFO='6:25:4'
LIBXML_VERSION_NUMBER='20425'
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO='makeinfo'
MV=''
M_LIBS=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='libxml2'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PYTHON=''
PYTHON_INCLUDES=''
PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES=''
PYTHON_SUBDIR=''
PYTHON_VERSION=''
RANLIB=''
RDL_LIBS=''
RM=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
TAR=''
TEST_REGEXPS=''
TEST_SCHEMAS=''
TEST_THREADS=''
THREAD_CFLAGS=''
THREAD_LIBS=''
U=''
VERSION='2.4.25-special'
WIN32_EXTRA_LDFLAGS=''
WIN32_EXTRA_LIBADD=''
WITH_C14N=''
WITH_CATALOG=''
WITH_DEBUG=''
WITH_DOCB=''
WITH_FTP=''
WITH_HTML=''
WITH_HTTP=''
WITH_ICONV=''
WITH_MEM_DEBUG=''
WITH_PYTHON_FALSE=''
WITH_PYTHON_TRUE=''
WITH_REGEXPS=''
WITH_SCHEMAS=''
WITH_THREADS=''
WITH_TRIO=''
WITH_TRIO_SOURCES_FALSE=''
WITH_TRIO_SOURCES_TRUE=''
WITH_XINCLUDE=''
WITH_XPATH=''
WITH_XPTR=''
XINCLUDE_OBJ=''
XML_CFLAGS=''
XML_INCLUDEDIR=''
XML_LIBDIR=''
XML_LIBS=''
XPATH_OBJ=''
XPTR_OBJ=''
Z_CFLAGS=''
Z_LIBS=''
ac_ct_AS=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DLLTOOL=''
ac_ct_F77=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
ac_ct_RANLIB=''
ac_ct_STRIP=''
am__include=''
am__quote=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-mingw32'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='mingw32'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${prefix}/share'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-pc-mingw32'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='mingw32'
host_vendor='pc'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/info'
install_sh='/c/Users/name/Documents/libxml2-2.4.25-special/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${prefix}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE "libxml2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define VERSION "2.4.25-special"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Possibly related, but maybe not a dup since this is windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461703/autoconf-problem-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables?rq=1

Comment: @robert: Updated with `config.log` file.

Comment: @robert: I seen the link, but I don't get an syntax error; and I have no a configure.c file here.

Comment: First, let's see if MinGW is installed correctly: can you successfully run `gcc conftest.c` from the command line?

Comment: On regular cmd, it's ok. But on `MSYS` it given an `gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`. I tried compile a file that I created by using `vi`. I can see my file by using `ls` command.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Fixed. Now I can compile the C file.

Comment: @Jack: by "fixed", do you mean that the configure script now works as well? And just out of curiosity (I'm not very familiar with the MSYS environment), was the problem something to do with the PATH in MSYS?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: The problem was in a new `MinGW` version that I'd installed(`4.7`). This version version aren't compiling any C code for me. Then, when the MSYS installation asked "do you have mingw installed?"(if you type "y", you should give the string path of mingw)  I typed: "n". So, by using older gcc version I was able to compiler a C program and then run the `./configure` file.

Comment: ...it are compiling the library now; if I install with successfully the library, I will post it as answer.

Comment: the build failed of some way. The ´libxml2.a` don't exists in `./libs` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

The problem was in a new MinGW version that I'd installed(`4.7`). This version version aren't compiling any C code for me. Then, when the `MSYS` installation asked "do you have mingw installed?"I typed: "n". So, by using older `gcc` version I was able to compiler a C program and then run the `./configure` and `make` files.